# How do I remove rows with duplicate info in a CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have some CSVs that have many columns and hundreds of rows. The columns are: `CompanyName, Website, Address, PhoneNumber, Email1, Email2, Email3`.

What I need is to remove all rows that have duplicated info. The issue is that for a row to be a duplicate, it doesn't have to have ALL entries be identical, it just needs to have at least 1 that is identical.

Here is an example of two rows that have almost all identical information except the `CompanyName` is different. This is just 1 permutation of this issue.

[image]

So the key thing is basically any two rows, that share the same value in 1 column, one of those rows should be deleted.

So if any two rows have the same `CompanyName`, `Email Address`, `Phone Number`, etc, 1 should be deleted.

What's the best way to approach this?

**Edit 1**

I would prefer creating a new, modified CSV, that has the duplicated rows eliminated. Largely because I don't want to risk damaging/corrupting the existing CSV.

**Edit 2**

Note that what I am really trying to do is avoid the N+1 problem, where I am comparing each row against every other row in an 800 row CSV. Or is that not possible to do given my objective?

Comment: What are you doing with this data? Is it a one-time thing or you'll be importing CSVs like this on a regular basis?

Comment: @EduardoSampaio I will be importing CSVs like this on a regular basis. I have a script that creates these CSVs, so I want to just write a method that sanitizes them.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions for you, one is just using `sort` *(untested)*:

```
sort -u -t, -k1,1 -k2,2 (etc. one for each column you want unique) file
```

Or if you are importing this data into a database, you could create a temporary table on it, where all columns are unique and just insert all of the CSV data into it, ignoring unique constraint exceptions.

Comment: Not importing the data into a database. I want to store it in another CSV. That `sort` command is a Ruby command? Or is that a `bash` command or something?

Comment: Yes, `sort` is a bash command. I really doubt you can write any algorithm in Ruby that will have a better performance than `sort`.